# Computing the change of coordinate matrix from one basis to another

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

> Given the bases *a* = {(0,2),(2,1)} and *b* = {(1,0),(1,1)} compute the change of coordinate matrix from basis *a* to *b*.
> Then, given the coordinates of *z* with respect to the basis *a* as (2,2), use the previous question to compute the coordinates of *z* with respect to the basis *b*.

The way I understood the first part was that I have to multiply the vectors of *b* by the coordinates of the vectors of *a* to compute the change of coordinate matrix from *a* to *b*.  This gives me the following matrix: \begin{bmatrix}2&3\\2&1\end{bmatrix}

For the second part, I then have to take the inverse of the matrix I got from above and then multiply it by the coordinates of *z* to get the coordinates of *z* with respect to the basis *b*.  The inverse of the matrix is: \begin{bmatrix}-1/4&3/4\\1/2&-1/2\end{bmatrix} which I then multiply by (2,2) to get the coordinates of *z* with respect to basis *b*

I am not sure that is correct however.

Comment: the rows of the change of basis matrix consist of the coordinates of your basis vectors $a = (a_1,a_2)$ with respect to your basis $b = (b_1,b_2)$.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use the changes of coordinates between each basis and the standard basis.  So, you want: $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Then what is normally called the change of basis matrix from $a$ to $b$ would be the matrix that takes vectors written in terms of $b$ and returns them written in terms of $a$.  So we get the matrix $C$, where $C=A^{-1}B$.

For the second part apply $C^{-1}$ to $z$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the coordinates from the basis $a$ to the canonical basis (multiplying by $A$), then change from the canonical basis to the base $b$ (multiplying by $B^{-1}$ on the left). Finally you apply to $z$,

$$B^{-1}Az.$$

---

As a shortcut, you can compute $Az$ and solve the system

$$Bx=Az,$$ this spares computation (but does not give you the matrix).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{B} = \{b_1, b_2\}$ and $\mathcal{B}^{\prime} = \{b_1^{\prime}, b_2^{\prime}\}$ be two bases.

If $v$ is a vector expressed with respect to $\mathcal{B}$, then
$$v = \begin{bmatrix} b_{1} & b_{2}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
for some scalars $c_1$ and $c_2$. Since $\mathcal{B}^{\prime}$ is a basis, the elements of $\mathcal{B}$ can be expressed with respect to $\mathcal{B}^{\prime}$. Hence,
\begin{align}
v &= \begin{bmatrix} (d_1b_1^{\prime} + d_2b_2^{\prime}) & (d_3b_1^{\prime} + d_4b_2^{\prime}) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} b_{1}^{\prime} & b_{2}^{\prime}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} d_1 & d_3 \\ d_2 & d_4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
for some scalars $d_1, d_2, d_3$, and $d_4$.

The vector $\begin{bmatrix} d_1 & d_3 \\ d_2 & d_4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix}$ is the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}^{\prime}$.

In your case, $\mathcal{B} = a$, $\mathcal{B}^{\prime} = b$, and $\begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix} = z$. Can you determine $\begin{bmatrix} d_1 & d_3 \\ d_2 & d_4 \end{bmatrix}$?